# Recognizing touch position

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I have a WPF project which recognizes different inputs (e.g. finger, mouse, tagged objects) in the touch down method, I have an IF statement that recognizes if a tag is recognized and displays the data for the series and the value of the tag placed, then stores the data in the variable `string type` and displays it in the content of a label, the else recognizes if the touch is with a finger, and does the same thing.

However what I'm having trouble to achieve is being able to recognize the position in which a tag or finger is at the touch down poistion. I believe that a Point is needed to get the X&Y position of the touch but having tried multiple times with different things I cannot find a solution as to what parameters are needed.

The method

```
void SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    TouchDevice c = e.TouchDevice;
    

    //by default it is a blob
    string type = "Blob"; 
    Point p = c.GetPosition();
    if (c.GetIsTagRecognized() == true)
    {
        type = "Tag";
        type += (" Series: " + c.GetTagData().Series.ToString("X", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        type += (" Value: " + c.GetTagData().Value.ToString("X", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
     // type += (" Position: " //something here);
       
    }
    else if (c.GetIsFingerRecognized())
    {
        type = "Finger";
    }
    //display the type of item in a label
    InfoLabel.Content = type;
}
```

The errors received

> Error 1: 'Point' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Point' and 'System.Drawing.Point'
>
> Error 2: No overload for method 'GetPosition' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Are you looking for something like `TouchPoint p = e.GetTouchPoint(sender as IInputElement);`?

Comment: Must have edited, this message about 10 times! Yes that worked as I wanted. Thank you so much dkozl. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error 1: 'Point' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Point' and 'System.Drawing.Point'

You're using 2 namespaces:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
```

and both contain definition of `Point` and compiler cannot decide which one you want to use when you do

```
Point p = c.GetPosition();
```

to fix it you can use `var`:

```
var p = c.GetPosition();
```

> Error 2: No overload for method 'GetPosition' takes 0 arguments

As far as I can see `TouchDevice` does not have `GetPosition()` method but `TouchEventArgs` have [`TouchEventArgs.GetTouchPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs.gettouchpoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so instead you can do something like this:

```
var p = e.GetTouchPoint(sender as IInputElement).Position;
```